# Dividir una str en tres listas,segun el numero de caracteres que tenga cada linea

Tags: string, funciones, metodología

**Poseo una str con palabras de diferentes logitudes:**

```
['Bufalo', 'Buho', 'Buitre', 'Burro', 'Cormoran', 'Condor', 'Cotorra', 'Coyote'
, 'Halcon', 'Hamster', 'Hiena', 'Hipocampo', 'Hipopotamo', 'Holoturia', 'Hormiga',
'Lechuza', 'Lemur', 'Leon', 'Leonmarino', 'Leopardo', 'Jabali', 'Jabiru', 'Jerbo',
'Jirafa', 'Jaguar', 'Vaca', 'Varano', 'Venado', 'Vino', 'Tabano', 'Tejon', 'Tenia',
'Termita', 'Tiburon', 'Tigre', 'Tijereta', 'Asno', 'Atun', 'Avefria', 'Avestruz', 
'Telefono', 'Televisor', 'Portatiles', 'Gps', 'Drones', 'Consolas', 'Impresora', 
'Robots', 'MemoriaRam', 'Procesador', 'Camara', 'AirPods', 'Raspberry', 'Smartwatch', 
'Xiami', 'Samsung', 'Huawei', 'Analogico', 'Cibernetica', 'Circuito', 'Diseño', 
'Fusion', 'programacion', 'progreso', 'laser', 'lenguaje', 'logica', 'teoria', 
'termino', 'ingeniero', 'innovacion', 'interface', 'inversion', 'investigacion',
'laser', 'lenguaje', 'logica', 'maquina', 'mecanica', 'microchip', 'Violin', 
'Berimbau', 'laud', 'kamanche', 'lira', 'Flauta', 'Acordeon', 'Bajo', 'Guitarra', 
'Piano', 'Ukelele', 'Tambor', 'Violinchelo', 'laud', 'Banjo', 'Armonica', 
'Saxofon', 'Trompeta', 'Xilofono', 'Maracas', 'Fagot', 'Kalimba', 'Bateria', 'bongo', 
'botella', 'bougarabou', 'buk', 
'bulbul', 'guqin', 'gumbri', 'guira',
'guiro', 'laud', 'matofono', 'matraca',
'birra', 'mejorana', 'metalofono', 'ocarina', 'octabajo']
```

Deseo agregar en tres variables distintas los objetos de la **str** segun su **longitud**, y de alli construir las nuevas str con los metodos **upper,lower y capitalize**.

¿Me podrian regalar un consejo de como utilizar el metodo `len()` para realizar esta tarea o si existe otro metodo?

!GRACIAS¡

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que plasmes el algoritmo en papel y hagas corridas de escritorio, para validar su funcionalidad, así ejercitaras tu lógica, este ejemplo toma tu arreglo de palabras y lo categoriza en 3 tipos, palabras que son iguales o menores a 4, palabras menores o iguales  a 8 y mayores a 4 y finalmente palabras mayores a 8, este ejemplo esta en JavaScript pero creo que te puede servir la lógica que utilice:

```
let words = ['Bufalo', 'Buho', 'Buitre', 'Burro', 'Cormoran', 'Condor', 'Cotorra', 'Coyote'
    , 'Halcon', 'Hamster', 'Hiena', 'Hipocampo', 'Hipopotamo', 'Holoturia', 'Hormiga',
    'Lechuza', 'Lemur', 'Leon', 'Leonmarino', 'Leopardo', 'Jabali', 'Jabiru', 'Jerbo',
    'Jirafa', 'Jaguar', 'Vaca', 'Varano', 'Venado', 'Vino', 'Tabano', 'Tejon', 'Tenia',
    'Termita', 'Tiburon', 'Tigre', 'Tijereta', 'Asno', 'Atun', 'Avefria', 'Avestruz',
    'Telefono', 'Televisor', 'Portatiles', 'Gps', 'Drones', 'Consolas', 'Impresora',
    'Robots', 'MemoriaRam', 'Procesador', 'Camara', 'AirPods', 'Raspberry', 'Smartwatch',
    'Xiami', 'Samsung', 'Huawei', 'Analogico', 'Cibernetica', 'Circuito', 'Diseño',
    'Fusion', 'programacion', 'progreso', 'laser', 'lenguaje', 'logica', 'teoria',
    'termino', 'ingeniero', 'innovacion', 'interface', 'inversion', 'investigacion',
    'laser', 'lenguaje', 'logica', 'maquina', 'mecanica', 'microchip', 'Violin',
    'Berimbau', 'laud', 'kamanche', 'lira', 'Flauta', 'Acordeon', 'Bajo', 'Guitarra',
    'Piano', 'Ukelele', 'Tambor', 'Violinchelo', 'laud', 'Banjo', 'Armonica',
    'Saxofon', 'Trompeta', 'Xilofono', 'Maracas', 'Fagot', 'Kalimba', 'Bateria', 'bongo',
    'botella', 'bougarabou', 'buk',
    'bulbul', 'guqin', 'gumbri', 'guira',
    'guiro', 'laud', 'matofono', 'matraca',
    'birra', 'mejorana', 'metalofono', 'ocarina', 'octabajo']
let min_four = [];
let min_eight = [];
let max_words = [];

if (words.length != 0)//Valida la longitud del arreglo
{
    for (var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) //Iteramos dentro del arreglo
    {
        if (words[n].length != 0) //La longitud de la palabra es mayor a 0
        {
            if (words[n].length <= 4) { //La longitud de la palabra es mayor a 0 y menor o igual a 4
                min_four.push(words[n]) //La propiedad push() indica que añadiremos un elemento al arreglo
            }
            else
            {
                if (words[n].length <= 8) { //La longitud de la palabra es menor o igual a 8
                    min_eight.push(words[n]);
                }
                else
                {
                    max_words.push(words[n]); //Las palabras son mayores a 8 caracteres
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(min_four);
console.log(min_eight);
console.log(max_words);
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes backjunior,

Disculpa pero no acabo de entender del todo que quieres hacer ni en que lenguage.

Por si te sirve como consejo, te mando un pedazo de código en python. Quizá te sirva para empezar.

```
palabras = ['Bufalo', 'Buho', 'Buitre', 'Burro', 'Cormoran']
        
for i in range(10):
    for word in palabras:
        if len(word) == i:
            print (word, len(word))
```

Con esto tendrás las palabras ordenadas.
Si quieres añadir esas palabras a tres variables:

- crearía esos 3 array
- cambiaría el print por un variable.append
- Con un par de if deberías poder decidir hacia donde quieres añadir esas palabras

He reducido bastante la variable que has propuesto, pero espero que te sea de ayuda para empezar!

## CODE:

```
    smallWords = []
    midWords = []
    longWords = []
    
    for i in range(10):
        for word in words:
            if len(word) == i:
                if len(word) < 5:
                    smallWords.append(word)
                if len(word) >= 5 and len(word) <= 7:
                    midWords.append(word)
                if len(word) > 7:
                    longWords.append(word)
# Result: 
    --- print (smallWords)
    ['Buho']
    --- print (midWords)
    ['Burro', 'Bufalo', 'Buitre']
    --- print (longWords)
    ['Cormoran']
```

Comment: Solamente piense en qué pasará si tiene un arreglo con palabras de más de 10 carácteres. El código tendría que reformularlo. Además de que al tener un bucle anidado genera mal rendimiento, dele una mirada a la notación Big O

Answer (score 0):

Le recomiendo usar una estructura de datos para la salida y así no tiene necesidad de usar ciclos `for` anidados, los cuales afectan el rendimiento y son difíciles de mantener. El método `len()` en python cuenta la cantidad de "items" que hay dentro de un array, en el caso de `len(['Bufalo', 'Buho', 'Buitre', 'Burro'])` genera como resultado 4.

Como un string se tiene unos algunos métodos compartidos con los arrays, si aplica `len("búfalo")` da como resultado 6.

Use este código con estructura de datos para la salida:

```
palabras = ['Bufalo', 'Buho', 'Buitre', 'Burro', 'Cormoran', 'Condor', 'Cotorra', 'Coyote'
, 'Halcon', 'Hamster', 'Hiena', 'Hipocampo', 'Hipopotamo', 'Holoturia', 'Hormiga',
'Lechuza', 'Lemur', 'Leon', 'Leonmarino', 'Leopardo', 'Jabali', 'Jabiru', 'Jerbo',
'Jirafa', 'Jaguar', 'Vaca', 'Varano', 'Venado', 'Vino', 'Tabano', 'Tejon', 'Tenia',
'Termita', 'Tiburon', 'Tigre', 'Tijereta', 'Asno', 'Atun', 'Avefria', 'Avestruz', 
'Telefono', 'Televisor', 'Portatiles', 'Gps', 'Drones', 'Consolas', 'Impresora', 
'Robots', 'MemoriaRam', 'Procesador', 'Camara', 'AirPods', 'Raspberry', 'Smartwatch', 
'Xiami', 'Samsung', 'Huawei', 'Analogico', 'Cibernetica', 'Circuito', 'Diseño', 
'Fusion', 'programacion', 'progreso', 'laser', 'lenguaje', 'logica', 'teoria', 
'termino', 'ingeniero', 'innovacion', 'interface', 'inversion', 'investigacion',
'laser', 'lenguaje', 'logica', 'maquina', 'mecanica', 'microchip', 'Violin', 
'Berimbau', 'laud', 'kamanche', 'lira', 'Flauta', 'Acordeon', 'Bajo', 'Guitarra', 
'Piano', 'Ukelele', 'Tambor', 'Violinchelo', 'laud', 'Banjo', 'Armonica', 
'Saxofon', 'Trompeta', 'Xilofono', 'Maracas', 'Fagot', 'Kalimba', 'Bateria', 'bongo', 
'botella', 'bougarabou', 'buk', 
'bulbul', 'guqin', 'gumbri', 'guira',
'guiro', 'laud', 'matofono', 'matraca',
'birra', 'mejorana', 'metalofono', 'ocarina', 'octabajo']

respuesta = {}

for palabra in palabras:
  longitud_palabra = len(palabra)
  arreglo_anterior = respuesta.get(longitud_palabra)
  if arreglo_anterior == None:
    arreglo_anterior = []
  
  arreglo_anterior.append(palabra)
  respuesta[longitud_palabra] = arreglo_anterior
  
print(respuesta)
```

La cual genera la siguiente respuesta:

```
{
  6: ['Bufalo', 'Buitre', 'Condor', 'Coyote', 'Halcon', 'Jabali', 'Jabiru', 'Jirafa', 'Jaguar', 'Varano', 'Venado', 'Tabano', 'Drones', 'Robots', 'Camara', 'Huawei', 'Diseño', 'Fusion', 'logica', 'teoria', 'logica', 'Violin', 'Flauta', 'Tambor', 'bulbul', 'gumbri'],
  4: ['Buho', 'Leon', 'Vaca', 'Vino', 'Asno', 'Atun', 'laud', 'lira', 'Bajo', 'laud', 'laud'],
  5: ['Burro', 'Hiena', 'Lemur', 'Jerbo', 'Tejon', 'Tenia', 'Tigre', 'Xiami', 'laser', 'laser', 'Piano', 'Banjo', 'Fagot', 'bongo', 'guqin', 'guira', 'guiro', 'birra'],
  8: ['Cormoran', 'Leopardo', 'Tijereta', 'Avestruz', 'Telefono', 'Consolas', 'Circuito', 'progreso', 'lenguaje', 'lenguaje', 'mecanica', 'Berimbau', 'kamanche', 'Acordeon', 'Guitarra', 'Armonica', 'Trompeta', 'Xilofono', 'matofono', 'mejorana', 'octabajo'],
  7: ['Cotorra', 'Hamster', 'Hormiga', 'Lechuza', 'Termita', 'Tiburon', 'Avefria', 'AirPods', 'Samsung', 'termino', 'maquina', 'Ukelele', 'Saxofon', 'Maracas', 'Kalimba', 'Bateria', 'botella', 'matraca', 'ocarina'],
  9: ['Hipocampo', 'Holoturia', 'Televisor', 'Impresora', 'Raspberry', 'Analogico', 'ingeniero', 'interface', 'inversion', 'microchip'],
  10: ['Hipopotamo', 'Leonmarino', 'Portatiles', 'MemoriaRam', 'Procesador', 'Smartwatch', 'innovacion', 'bougarabou', 'metalofono'],
  3: ['Gps', 'buk'],
  11: ['Cibernetica', 'Violinchelo'],
  12: ['programacion'],
  13: ['investigacion']
}
```

Y para acceder a la respuesta se accede como cualquier diccionario.